# How to increment static counter in parent class on object creation

Tags: python, oop, static

I am attempting to implement a static counter in a parent class, but the counter has the same value in all objects.

In the following example, I expect `id` to be incremented every time an object is created. Instead, I'm getting the same `id` (in this example, `18`) for every object.

Why is the static `id` property not acting as expected? It's declared outside the constructor in the super-class. I expect `self.id` within each object to inherit the static incremented value, and so it should change with every object created.

I need to number each of the objects.

```
class Cheese:
    id = 17
    def __init__(self):
        self.id += 1

class Cheddar(Cheese):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name_ = name

def main():
    cabot_clothbound = Cheddar("Cabot Clothbound")
    kerrygold = Cheddar("Kerrygold")
    tillamook = Cheddar("Tillamook")

    print(f"Cabot Clothbound: {cabot_clothbound.id}")
    print(f"Kerrygold: {kerrygold.id}")
    print(f"Tillamook: {tillamook.id}")

main()
```

Expected Output:

```
18
19
20
```

Actual Output

```
18
18
18
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your code to:

```
class Cheese:
    id = 17
    def __init__(self):
        Cheese.id += 1
        self.id = Cheese.id
```

Comment: Thanks @quar whatever your name is :)

Comment: Yes I see now. I wasn't properly referencing the class variable, and also need to grab the _current_ value and preserve it in each object. tytytyI<3uty

Comment: @kmiklas You're welcome, I see what went wrong, given the fact that you have ton of c++ experience and not much python experience.